# Spring boot log level does not work for subpackage

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-logback

I have a spring boot application where I need to change log level to info for my application and error for the library it uses. Both of them have the same parent package structure:

```
com.org.product.library
com.org.product.module
```

I added the following to the application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    com.org.product.library: ERROR
    com.org.product.module: INFO
```

But now the module is also logging only errors.

This is how Logger is invoked:

```
public static void info(String msgCode, String msg) {
    if (isInfoEnabled()) {
        getLoggerEngine().info(msgCodeMarker(msgCode), msg);
    }

}

static Logger getLoggerEngine() {
    //slf4j LoggerFactory
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log.class);
}
```

Also there is this spring-logback.xml configuration in the library:

```
<logger name="com.org" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="json" />
</logger>

<!-- By default will log warnings and above-->
<!-- set to other level for development if needed -->
<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="json" />
</root>
```

Comment: Do you have any other logging levels specified somewhere else?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but it works. I also assume that you have some other configuration that affects the logging level. And please show how you create the logger

Comment: Updated the description with the Logger